# How can i add more locales to Symfony/Icu 1.0.x?

Tags: symfony, icu, symfony-2.3

Symfony2 Form localization now depends on Symfony/Intl and Symfony/Icu components.
If the server you run you application has ICU lib version lower than 4.0 you must use the Symfony/Icu 1.0.x component which emulates the ICU lib.

The problem is that it only has support for en locale. My project needs a few more.
How could i extend or add support for more locales into Symfony/Icu 1.0.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation of intl component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html) suggests, a full replacement of the intl extension is not the goal of the component:

> The replacement layer is limited to the locale "en". If you want to use other locales, you should install the intl extension instead.

If you're working on an internationalized app, you should install the intl extension. The component is there to avoid a hard dependency on the extension (since not every app needs internationalization).

Comment: Jakub, the problem is, that there is an installed intl extension, but the icu library version is too low to parse the res files for it. Upgrading icu is not the solution, because there are other applications which depend on the old icu library..

Comment: @LaurynasMališauskas Then, this seems more a devops problem.

Comment: from my point of view, adding more stub locales should be possible in this component. Now the solution is to remove all the localized input fields from the forms..